# Warning: node-5.0.0 already installed, it's just not linked

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I am trying to install node js. I am getting the following error . Any idea?

```
brew install node
Warning: node-5.0.0 already installed, it's just not linked
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to run:

```
brew link node
```

What you're doing is telling Brew to create a symlink for the node executable to the /usr/bin (or /usr/local/bin) directory, as far as I am aware.

Comment: Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.

Comment: Give brew write access to /usr/local/share.

Comment: how to do give write access?

Comment: still i am getting the same issue. Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0... 
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.

Comment: That's odd. I'll look at it some more.

Comment: I saw this answer, chown -R <yourusername>:<yourgroupname> systemtap. But what  is username and group name refer to?

Comment: Try giving brew write access to /usr/local as well, temporarily. This might not work if you are using OS X 10.11.

Comment: sudo chmod a+w /usr/local --> this also doesnot work brother

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`

Comment: "sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local" worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For this issue run

```
brew link homebrew/versions/node<version no>
```

To know why, you can surf [here](http://tinyurl.com/zmgstv5).

Comment: `brew search node` will show you the installed versions.Then you can unsinstall the unused and link the needed version.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the below command to override all the conflicts.

```
brew link --overwrite node
```